# eclipse fails to "build workspace" on large android files...?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, dalvik

i have a severe problem with eclipse, where i need to compile a somewhat larger class. by "larger" i mean, the class has about 5000 lines of code...

problem is that on saving this project, eclipse takes several seconds (30-40) to "build the workspace". to be exact, it says "50%" and keeps saying that for 30-40 seconds. then, it breaks with the following error:

[console]:

`[2010-07-09 15:28:39 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: null`

`[2010-07-09 15:28:39 - myProject] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: null`

[problems window]:

`Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: null`

this error is reproducible and keeps popping up until i comment out several thousands LOC, so that the file still has this 5k LOC, but ~2000 of them are comments. THEN it works...

i know that 5000 LOC are no really good programming style, but i need to do it this way for now ... (i have to write this much records to a sqlite database and since sqlite doesnt feature multiple sql-queries in one rawQuery-command i have to execute a single rawQuery() for each and every data record i need to push into the db.... - until i write a file reader to read this data from a file (that needs verification etc)), i'm stuck with this solution...)

how do i get eclipse and the android sdk to accept files this big?

(system: ubuntu 10.04 x86, eclipse 3.6)

Comment: do you have to do that (the queries stuff) in a dynamic way in your application, or is it something done once only?

Comment: it is done only once atm. but since the database is still under developments (both in structure and content), i need to do this again if something changes there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the size of a class's bytecode must not exceed 64k in Dalvik. You'll have to split the class into smaller ones.