# Eclipse Android SDK - 'Building Workspace' deadlock

Tags: android, eclipse

- I have two Android projects in my Eclipse workspace (one is a library project used by the other)
- Compiling the first (library) project works fine
- The second one always hangs (at 98% complete)

I know there are similar issues covered in articles and blogs, but none of these guides seem to work.

So far, I have:

- Cleaned projects
- Created clean workspaces
- Even had to do a clean install of Ubuntu (so all Eclipse, Java, Android SDK are clean)

Please help! I am at the end of my ropes with this problem!

I am running Ubuntu 10.04, Eclipse 3.5.2 (everything is 32-bit). This setup had been working for a month or so, and just broke the other day.)

Comment: What does your eclipse log file say??

Comment: Have you reviewed this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212941/eclipse-fails-to-build-workspace-on-large-android-files

Comment: post any interesting exceptions from ${workspace}/.metadata/.log

Comment: It was a corrupted image file in another project (see below). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your comment suggestions.

I went through the logs, and they were not very informative.

It turns out the problem was with a corrupt PNG image (located in the library project -- which was compiling correctly!)

It was [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/5a8c717092e3b527?pli=1) that led me to search the 'drawable' directories.

Answer (score 13):

> Building workspace gets stuck at 99%
>   If Eclipse hangs while "building workspace", try killing any running adb processes in the background. There actually seem to be a variety of possible causes, but when using the ADT Eclipse plugins, this might work.

See here: http://android-sdk.wikispaces.com/Building+workspace+stuck+at+99%25

Answer (score 7):

I found that when i plugged in a device while eclipse was running, it would halt progress on building. Unplugging it immediately fixed things. I had some bad drivers it seems.

Comment: Thanks, that was spot on for me.. Only seems to have started more recently though (and only ever happened on mac/unix for me).

Comment: Excellent!!! I struggled with this issue for more than 3 hrs. Finally you post solved my problem. Thanks a lot!!!!!

Comment: Wow, this helped. I unplugged my device, and now all of sudden the problem is gone.